# Python dict to csv in columns format

Tags: python, csv

I have the following dict

```
items = {'people': ['Peter', 'Danny'], 'numbers': [1,2,3,4], 'cities': ['London']}
```

And I would like to write that dict to a CSV file by columns, that is, with the following format:

```
people,numbers,cities
Peter,1,London
Danny,2,
     ,3,
     ,4,
```

My current approach won't work because I get the CSV file by rows:

```
people,Peter,Danny
numbers,1,2,3,4
cities,London
```

How can I do what I need?

Comment: You could check out the pandas package, it has many methods to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can use Pandas for that, which only takes two lines

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(items).fillna('').to_csv('file_path')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` (`itertools.izip_longest` in Python2):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
import csv
items = {'people': ['Peter', 'Danny'], 'numbers': [1,2,3,4], 'cities': ['London']}
headers = ['people', 'numbers', 'cities']
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
  full_listing = [['' if not b else b for b in i] for i in zip_longest(*[items[c] for c in headers])]
  write = csv.writer(f)
  write.writerows([headers]+full_listing)
```

Output:

```
people,numbers,cities
Peter,1,London
Danny,2,
     ,3,
     ,4,
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to calculate the length of the longest list in your dictionary, and then append `''` to all the lists so they have this length.

```
num_rows = max((len(x) for x in items.values()))
items = {k: items[k] + [''] * (num_rows - len(items[k])) for k in items}
print(items)
#{'cities': ['London', '', '', ''],
# 'numbers': [1, 2, 3, 4],
# 'people': ['Peter', 'Danny', '', '']}
```

Then write the `dict` to csv using the `csv` module.

Or you can build a `pandas DataFrame` from your dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(items)
print(df)
#   cities  numbers people
#0  London        1  Peter
#1                2  Danny
#2                3       
#3                4
```

Now you can write it to a file using the `to_csv()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to rely on external dependencies like *pandas*, you can quickly achieve this in pure python with `join` method of `str` objects.

```py
items = {'people': ['Peter', 'Danny'],
         'numbers': [1, 2, 3, 4],
         'cities': ['London']}


def to_csv(items):
    # names of columns
    header = ','.join(list(items.keys()))
    # building lines
    lines = list()
    max_len = max([len(items[key]) for key in items.keys()])
    for i in range(max_len):
        lines.append(
            ','.join(
                [str(items[key][i]) for key in items.keys()
                 if i < len(items[key])]))
    # return header and lines separated by new lines
    return '\n'.join([header] + lines)


print(to_csv(items))
```

outputs :

```
people,numbers,cities
Peter,1,London
Danny,2,
,3,
,4,
```